# Определить наличие интернета на устройстве (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Ищу простое и стабильное решение для определения наличия подключения к интернету на устройстве:

```
internet()
{
  if () {return true;}
  else {return false;}
}

onPressed: ()
{
  if (internet() == true) {}
}
```

пробовал так, но что-то криво работает:

```
  internet() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://paybot.top/test.json');
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: "что-то криво работает" - уточните. Кнопка "править" под вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("1"),
              onPressed: () {
                internet().then((result) {
                  if (result) {
                    print("true");
                  }
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> internet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: вот такая ошибка возникает https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z3nmv1q96l3o6g/Screenshot_20200425-190443.png?dl=0

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z3nmv1q96l3o6g/Screenshot_20200425-190443.png?dl=0] @MiT

Comment: @АлексейБондарь обновил ответ.

Comment: работает, спасибо!:)